# Render an attribute of a model as the HTML page title

Tags: javascript, ember.js

How can I render the `fullName` of the `User` model as the HTML page title instead of the `...` in `"Details for ..."`?

```
App.User = DS.Model.extend({
  firstName    : DS.attr('string'),
  lastName     : DS.attr('string'),

  fullName: function() {
    return this.get('firstName') + ' ' + this.get('lastName');
  }.property('firstName', 'lastName'),      
});

App.UserRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  model: function(params){
    return this.store.find('user', params.user_id);
  },

  activate: function() {
    $(document).attr('title', 'Details for ...');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can observe the `fullName` property in the `UserController`, and update the title, when the property change:

```
App.UserController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  updateTitle: function() {    
    $(document).attr('title', 'Details for ' + this.get('fullName'));
  }.observes('fullName')
})
```

To just set the title once, without bindings, you can use, the following:

```
App.UserRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  originalTitle: null,
  model: function(params){
    return this.store.find('user', params.user_id);
  },
  activate: function() {
    // save the original title
    this.set('originalTitle', $(document).attr('title'));
    // we use Ember.run.next because the currentModel property isn't avaliable
    Ember.run.next(this, function() {
      // the resolved result from model method, is set in the currentModel property
      $(document).attr('title', 'Details for ' + this.currentModel.get('fullName'));
    });        
  },
  deactivate: function() {
    // restore the original title
    $(document).attr('title', this.get('originalTitle'));
  }
});
```

This is the jsbin http://emberjs.jsbin.com/ExAkulA/3/edit

**UPDATE**

I think that using `afterModel` instead of `activate` method, is the better way to implement it:

```
App.UserRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  originalTitle: null,
  model: function(params){        
    return this.store.find('user', params.user_id);
  },
  afterModel: function(model) {
    // save the original title
    this.set('originalTitle', $(document).attr('title'));    
    // no hacks here, we have the resolved model avaliable
    $(document).attr('title', 'Details for ' + model.get('fullName'));    
  },
  deactivate: function() {
    // restore the original title
    $(document).attr('title', this.get('originalTitle'));
  }
});
```

Live demo http://emberjs.jsbin.com/ExAkulA/5/edit

Comment: Is it possible to use the `activate` hook in the route too? I'd like to set the HTML title once at the beginning.

Comment: I updated again. That time we use afterModel instead of activate, because in the afterModel we have the resolved model, so no hacks needed.